# Sass - Class name wildcard

Tags: sass

Is it possible to have a wildcard class name?

for example i have a few divs `.div-one`,`.div-two`,`.div-three` etc
Is there a way for me to use the below in sass to select all the divs with that name or is it best just to give one class that covers all and unique classes on each?

`.div-*{}`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In CSS you can use the attribute selector with `^`:

`div[class^="div-"]` ==> Selects all `div` with a `class` attribute value starting with *"div-"*

**Example:**

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div[class^="div-"] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-one"></div>
<div class="div-two"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="div-three"></div>
```

### Update

As @FreePender says, if the CSS class isn't the one in the attribute's value, it doesn't work. Another solution is to use the attribute selector with `*`:

`div[class*="div-"]` ==> Selects all `div` with a `class` attribute value containing *"div-"*.

This way it would also match a CSS class named `nodiv-one` for example, but it's not something that happens normally.

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div[class*="div-"] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-one"></div>
<div class="div-two"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="myclass div-three"></div>
```

Comment: @nydame works with SCSS syntax (primary syntax in Sass), if you are using old Sass syntax remove braces and semicolons

Comment: I just tried this, and it seems to work for selectors that need to begin and end with particular substrings: `[class^="img"], 
[class^="hero"] {
  &[class$="responsive"] {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}`. This correctly targets my `<img class="img_article_responsive">`.

Comment: You can do `[class^="div-"], [class*=" div-"]`.

Answer (score 16):

Small point but I noticed that when nesting this rule in Sass, you need to put the ampersand right against the opening square bracket.

This doesn't work:

```
.zoomed {
  & [class*=" aspect-"] {
    margin-bottom: $spacer * 4.0;
  }
}
```

But this does:

```
.zoomed {
  &[class*=" aspect-"] {
    margin-bottom: $spacer * 4.0;
  }
}
```

Note the position of the ampersand.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is cool in theory, but in the latest chrome as of today:

For the CSS rule:

```
[class^="div-"]
```

the markup

```
class="div-something other-class"
```

matches, whereas:

```
class="other-class div-something"
```

does not match

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You are right, only works if the class with teh name *div-something* is the first, but this is not an answer, which is your proposal? Another solution is use [class*="div-"]

Comment: This is a fascinating observation. Why, oh why, would the CSS parser behave this way? Is this a bug? Or "working as designed"? Citation, anyone?

Comment: @BenJohnson: This is as designed. `[name^="value"]` just means "attribute `name`'s value starts with `value`. Makes sense b/c it's for any kind of attribute values, not just `class="…"`. Only for `class` attributes, CSS "knows" that multiple values are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this method to do. Create a mixin:

```
@mixin myDIV($name, $color, $color-hover) {
    .div-#{$name} {
        a {
            color: #{$color};
            &:focus, &:hover {
                color: #{$color-hover};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@include myDIV('one', $blue, $blue-hover);
@include myDIV('two', $green, $green-hover);
@include myDIV('three', $red, $red-hover);
```

You may change the variables ($blue) and css properties to suits your styles.

Comment: how in the hell would you target this then from your html

Comment: i dont think you can do <div class="myDiv('one', green, something)"

Comment: @colinrickels: Reference the mixin and read up on [SASS interpolation](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375). `.div-#{$name}` means create a string appending the name param to `div-`. In your HTML: `<div class="div-one">Whatever</div>`.

To the OP, I was curious if there would be a way to reference a class that begins with some partial string and ends with another, ignoring whatever comes in between. I think the answer is no.